# Flexmojos, Flexunit4: adl returns Unexpected return code 9

Tags: apache-flex, air, maven-3, flexmojos, flexunit4

I got problem when running flexunit4 unit test

```
Flexmojos 4.2-beta
     Apache License - Version 2.0 (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Running tests /Users/mordesku/NetBeansProjects/way2learn/builder/target/test-classes/TestRunner.swf
[LAUNCHER] Using regular flashplayer tests
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time Elapsed: 0 sec
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:10.516s
Finished at: Fri Dec 07 09:53:52 CET 2012
Final Memory: 11M/213M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.2-beta:test-run (default-test-run) on project builder: Unexpected return code 9 - /Users/mordesku/NetBeansProjects/way2learn/builder/target/test-classes/TestRunner.swf -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

When i am running adl from command line (from target directory), got this output:

```
jablecznik:test-classes mordesku$ adl TestRunner.xml 
error while loading initial content
jablecznik:test-classes mordesku$
```

Root node of TestRunner.xml looks like this:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">
```

When I changed it to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5">
```

Test from command line run normally.

Has anyone has the same problem as i? How configure flexmojos to output TestRunner.xml witch difrent version of airapplication version?

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version? 4.0-RC2 will probably still be too old, but 5.0-beta migth do the trick.

Comment: there are problem with unit test on 5.0-beta (http://www.mail-archive.com/flex-mojos@googlegroups.com/msg10718.html) it should be fixed in 5.1-beta but i can't build it from sources. There are missing dependencys.

Comment: Then I might suggest switching to [GradleFx](http://gradlefx.github.com/) (as it doesn't require AIR to run the unit tests), but that would be shameless self-promotion ;)